# eclipse-inst-win64.exe won't open

Tags: java, eclipse

**Dispite installed "jdk-13.0.1_windows-x64_bin" and "jre-8u231-windows-x64"  "eclipse-inst-win64.exe" won't open.**

I successfully installed latest Java-version on Windows 10, 64-bit

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Java>java -version
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)

C:\Users\Java>javac -version
javac 13.0.1
```

Now I downloaded the eclipse-inst-win64.exe, but when I want to open it, there is just the usual warning if you realy want to run this file, after accepting, just nothing happens.
I red in several threats that the problem might be that jdk/jre are 32-bit an the eclipse.exe 64-bit, but as you see in the command promt it is 64-bit.
I also saw several ways of the pathsettings of jdk/jre.
Mines look like these right now:

[Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggD6w.png)

[Edit Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FAuj.png)

I also downloaded the "eclipse-java-2019-12-R-win32-x86_64.zip" file.
When I open the eclipse.exe here at least the start screen with the eclipse-symbol comes up, but then an error occures and says:

"An error has occured. See the log file eclipse\configuration\1578426859232.log." There it gives me a bunch of code:

```
!SESSION 2020-01-07 11:54:19.030 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.14.0.I20191210-0610
java.version=1.8.0_231
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ant.launching 4 0 2020-01-07 11:54:19.630
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ant.launching [65]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.ibm.icu.text

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1837)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.i
```

......and so on...

At the top it says:

```
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product
```

Does that mean that the eclipse.exe is for 32-bit ? I am pretty sure that it has to be 64-bit.

After maybe one week I'm really frustrated with installing, uninstalling and hundreds of threats and youtube-how-to's.

Could please somebody help me!!! Thank you.

Comment: '-arch x86_64' means it is 64 bit - current releases of Eclipse are 64 bit only.

Comment: "I also downloaded the "eclipse-java-2019-12-R-win32-x86_64.zip" file. When I open the eclipse.exe..." Just to make sure, you *extracted* the contents of the zip file before trying to run `eclipse.exe`, right?

Comment: @nitind yes for sure, everything extracted!

Answer (score 0):

what eclipse version do you want to install?

you have the jdk 13 and the jre 8, maybe you have to get the same version

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I cant, not enough reputation  =(

Comment: OK, fully understood. But the appropriate way to resolve that is to ask and answer questions to gain reputation. See [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: @LucasPeralta Actually it don't really matter which version, I just finally wan't to get started with Java.